# Removing last 2D array from 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-structures

I have a three-dimensional `numpy` array with shape

```
(5,5,N)
```

When I add another 5x5 2D array to this 3D array using `numpy.dstack` the shape changes like

```
(5,5,N+1)
```

and so on.  I would like to remove the last 2D array I've added to the stack, such that it goes back to having the shape

```
(5,5,N)
```

and possibly `(5,5,N-1),(5,5,N-2),...`,etc.

What is the most pythonic way to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would index as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((5,5,5))
a.shape
(5, 5, 5)

b = np.ones((5, 5, 5))[:, :, :-1]
b.shape
(5, 5, 4)
```